# Vector and raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

Using ArcMap 10.2.2 I am currently doing an analysis on vegetation which requires both Raster and Vector data. only problem, how to make sure if these two data are compatible or identical in terms of resolution/scale?

For eg, when i want to overlay these two data, i want to make sure all the buildings are located on the same site (coordinate) in raster and vector ? is there any specific technique i should apply, apart from changing the coordinate system (data frame properties)?

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"?  Are your layers not lining up spatially?  What software are you using?

Comment: More information is needed on what data you have, what you mean by 'compatible', and what you're trying to do. Are you wanting to make sure data from each source is *coincident*? There will be no direct alignment (with one exception) of two differing sources where one is raster and one is vector because of the way those two methods store data. The question is more is it close enough. If you want to see a 10m square building on 30m resolution raster data, probably won't work so well. Determining that same building is within a 'forest' classified raster cell will, on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting raster to polygon. What your asking about is -that you need a spatial query, vector data is often utilized for spatial queries. I offer a minimal answer here, the idea could certainly be expanded. This is GIS 101. Good luck.